# Is it reasonable to create large numbers of gensyms?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols, sbcl

I am considering using large numbers of gensyms to differentiate between objects in a system I'm building (like refs in erlang).

Should I expect to run into system limits after creating large numbers of gensyms?

For reference, I'm using SBCL.

Comment: what would be a large number?

Comment: Want to do something daring? Try `(loop (prin1 (gensym)))`. DO NOT BLAME ME. Eventually this experiment seemed to suggest that there is no limit to the gensym number. Moreover, you can always replace the `G` of a  [`gensym`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gensym.htm) by giving another symbol as it's parameter.

Comment: @Mooncrater `gensym` takes a string or positive integer. It might work with symbol in some implementations but it's not portable.

Comment: Symbols in CL are often quite large objects.  If you just want a lot of unique cookies then `(cons nil nil)` is a good approach -- conses are usually two words which is almost as small as something can be.

Answer (score 2):

Different implementations use different amount of memory. From just testing the number of bytes used by `gensym` it is dependent on the argument you pass it and how unique that is from previous rounds..

If you have a macro that always pass a fixed number of strings to `gensym` it will use 0,5-1,5kB per. For every consecutive using the same argument its down to 65-150 bytes or so.

I had it make 65 byte gensyms for a while and stopped it well above 4 billions, but I don't know if that qualify since "large" is ambiguous.